# functors preserve homotopy pushouts and homotopy sums

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Let $\mathcal {M}$ and $\mathcal {N}$ be two cofibrantly generated model categories. Let $I$ be a small category. Then $\mathcal M^I$ has the projective model structure. The colimit functor is hence a left Quillen functor and we can define the homotopy colimit functor to be the left derived functor of the ordinary colimit functor.

Now let $F:\mathcal M\rightarrow \mathcal N$ be a functor preserving homotopy pushouts and homotopy infinite sums. I want to show that $F$ also preserves homotopy colimits.

So let $X:I\rightarrow M$ be a diagram in $\mathcal M$. Then we take the cofibrant replacement $X'=Q(X)$. Let $P=\oplus_{i\in I}{X'_i}$ and $Q=\bigoplus\limits_{m:i\rightarrow j\\\in\  I}P_m$ where $P_m$ is a copy of $P$ for each $m$. Define the codiagonal map $\nabla:Q\rightarrow P$ to be induced by the identity map of $P$ for each $m$ and $\mu:Q\rightarrow P$ defined by $\mu\circ q_m\circ p_i=p_j\circ X'(m) $ where $p_i:X'_i\rightarrow P$ and $q_m:P_m\rightarrow Q$ are the canonical morphisms. Then $\varinjlim X'$ is the pushout of the diagram defined by $\nabla$ and $\mu$.  In order to show the pushout of this diagram is the homotopy pushout, I need to show that at least one of $\mu$ and $\nabla$ is cofibration. I will be appreciated for any hint and comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither map is a cofibration in general. First, for $Q$ you must want $\oplus_m X'_i$. Now consider a cofibrant diagram $x\to y \to z$. In general the induced maps $x\oplus y\to z$ and $x\oplus x \to x$ are not cofibrations.

The proof of this result in a general model category is a bit complex. One proves it for simplicial homotopy colimits via a skeletal induction, then for categories of simplices by Kan extending to push a diagram down to $\Delta^{op}$, then for all categories by proving that the projection of the category of simplices of $I$ to $I$ is homotopy final. One can also combine the first two steps by working skeletally in an abstract Reedy category. I'm not sure whether there's an easier proof for the cofibrantly generated case.

Comment: So homotopy colimits are in general not constructed by using homotopy direct sums and homotopy pushout? Thank you for your answer, I'll accept it before checking the details since it's a little complicated for me.

Comment: @user12580 Not in the same way as ordinary colimits are, but they are, in a sense. A simplicial homotopy colimit is a geometric realization, which can be iteratively constructed out of pushouts, coproducts, and tensors with spheres, which themselves can be constructed out of pushouts.

Comment: I met with this problem again. B.Toen says that ' any homotopy colimit is a composition of homotopy pushouts and infinite (homotopy) sums' (Homotopy theory of dg-categories and derived Morita theory, proof of Sub-lemma 7.4). But in Sub-lemma 7.4 the model category is $\mathcal C^{op}-$Mod, where the homotopy colimit is the cone of a map between coproducts. I wonder if this is true more generally, i.e. when the model category is not pointed.

Comment: You gave me a lemma number but no paper. But a cone of a map between coproducts sounds to me like a homotopy colimit of a countable sequence. Anyway, I'm not sure what your claim is.

Comment: The link of the paper is: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0408337.pdf. You are right. I forgot that the Homotopy colimit I use most often is associated with a countable sequence. Then I have to rethink about it.

Comment: Yes, that’s an extremely special homotopy colimit, in that it can be constructed up to isomorphism just in the homotopy category. It gives very poor intuition for the general case.